# Classifying binary tree nodes using SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to solve the problem mentioned at the below link

https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/binary-search-tree-1/problem

I have written the following code.Please help me where i am going wrong

```
Select q.Node,case
              WHEN q.Node NOT IN q.Parent THEN 'Leaf' 
              WHEN q.Node IN q.Parent AND q.Node NOT IN q.Higher_Parent THEN 'Inner'
              WHEN q.Node IN q.Parent AND q.Node IN q.Higher_Parent THEN 'Root'
              END as NodeType
from (
SELECT B1.N as Node,B1.P as Parent,B2.P as Higher_Parent FROM 
BST B1 INNER JOIN BST B2 
ON B1.P = B2.N
ORDER BY Node ASC
) q

N P HP
1 2 5
2 5 NULL
3 2 5
6 8 5
8 5 NULL
9 8 5
```

Where should i modify the above code to work. Sure there are other concise codes for the same problem but please help me with this code for learning purpose.

Answer (score 2):

You can use CASE statement as follows:

```
SELECT N, CASE WHEN P IS NULL THEN 'Root' 
WHEN(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM BST WHERE P = T.N) > 0 THEN 'Inner'
ELSE 'Leaf'
END
FROM BST T
ORDER BY N;
```

Answer (score 1):

-- SQL SERVER working Solution

```
select N,
case 
when p is null then "Root"
when N in (select P from BST) THEN "Inner"
Else "Leaf" end as "P"
from BST
ORDER BY N;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select n.n,
  case 
    when max(p.n) is null then 'root'
    when max(c.n) is null then 'leaf'
    else 'inner'
  end as type
from bst n
left join bst p on p.n = n.p
left join bst c on c.p = n.n
group by n.n
```

Result:

```
| n |  type |
|---|-------|
| 1 |  leaf |
| 2 | inner |
| 3 |  leaf |
| 5 |  root |
| 6 |  leaf |
| 8 | inner |
| 9 |  leaf |
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ba3c76/1

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the `child` instead of the `higher parent`.

```
Select distinct c.n, 
        case when c.P is null then 'Root' 
             when b1.N is null then 'Leaf'
             else 'Inner' end
from BST c
left join BST b1
on c.N = b1.P
order by c.n
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use if else to solve it as well:

```
SELECT B.N, IF(B.P IS NULL, 'Root', IF((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM BST AS A WHERE A.P=B.N)>0,'Inner','Leaf')) 
FROM BST AS B 
ORDER BY B.N;
```

Answer (score 0):

See the below code. It might be easy to comprehend.

```sql
select n, 'Leaf' as nodename from bst
where n not in (select distinct p from bst where p is not null)
union
select n, 'Root' as nodename from bst
where p is null
union
select n, 'Inner' as nodename from bst
where n in (select distinct p from bst)
and p is not null
order by n asc;
```